# How to make the two div at the same line with the same height by browser

Tags: html, css, layout, dimensions

For example,this is my page layout,

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+       +  div2 +       +
+ div1   +     +       +
+       +       + div3  +
+       +++++++++       +
+       +       +       +
+       +       +++++++++
+       +               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

As shown,the div1 and div2 and div3 are at the same line,

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;min-height:500px;">
    <div id="div1" style="float:left;width:19%;height:100%"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:left;width:1%;height:100%">
       <img src="toggle.gif" /></div>
    <div id="div3" style="float:left;width:80%;height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

But they do not own the same height since the content of them are not the same.

Even I set the min-height of their parent element,and set the height of the to 100%.

I thought the div#container's height must > 500px.

And the three divs'height are all 100%,so they should take at least 500px.

But it seems that I am wrong.  I wonder what is going on?

BWT,inside the div2 there is just a icon which used to toggle the div1(use jquery),however when the div1 hidden,the div3 also take only 80% of the browser window,how to make the div2 and div3 take the whole window?

I know I can use the jquery to set their size,but I wonder if this can be implemented by  the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats don't calculate their height based on the height of their parent when you specify it in %. So your 100% doesn't refer to the height of the parent.
The approach that you should probably chase is using `position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0;` instead of `float:left; height 100%;` The only issue then is that the parent (in your case `container`) will not grow according to any of it's children's height. You should then either specify the height for `container` or make any of it's children columns not `position:abosute`.
Try this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:500px;position:relative;">
<div id="div1" style="background:blue; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width: 19%;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="background:red; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width: 1%; left: 19%;">
   <img src="toggle.gif" /></div>
<div id="div3" style="background:green; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:80%; left:20%;"></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jVRpK/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `min-height:500px;` to div1, div2 etc. Min-height property set on parent container doesn't mean that divs inside will have at last 500 px aswell.

Answer (score 0):

When you set div1, div2, div3 with float property, whichever is tallest will determine the height of container div.

Using [Faux Colums](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is one way to fix this.

Comment: Not really, your first statement is only true if the container has `overflow: hidden`. Otherwise container will have zero height in this case (unless `min-height` or `height` is set).